# Time complexity of a simple recurrence relation

Tags: computational-complexity, recursion

My professor told me that the following recurrence relation has linear complexity, but I'm not sure.

$T(n) = 3 T(n-1)+5$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T(n) & = 3 T(n-1)+5 \Rightarrow \\
T(n-1)     & = 3T(n-2) +5 \Rightarrow \\
T(n)-T(n-1)     & = 3T(n-1)-3T(n-2) \Rightarrow\\
T(n)     & = 4T(n-1)-3T(n-2) \Rightarrow \\
q^2 & = 4q - 3 \Rightarrow \\
q_{1,2} &= 3, 1 \Rightarrow\\
T(n) &= \alpha 1^n + \beta 3^n
\end{split}
\end{equation}

From these $T(0)=0, T(1)=5$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha=-5/2$ and $\beta=5/2$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(n) = \frac{-5}{2} +\frac{5}{2}3^n = O(3^n)$

How can be this linear? What am I missing?

Comment: Probably he/she meant that you can compute any member of the sequence in linear time. When you want $T(n)$ you need to calculate $n$ previous members of the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**what your professor meant**: the amount of calculations required to calculate $T(n)$ is linear in $n$ (most recurrences are).

**what you did** is calculating a closed form (or it seems to be an approximation) of $T(n)$ for a specific $n$.